# RuntimeException ajax request laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.4

I write a simple live chat converastion and works well, but in some cases,ajax request get error 500 (Internal Server Error) and the request is not complete

Record error in Laravel.log :

```
2017-02-28 16:49:54] production.ERROR: exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'The only supported ciphers are AES-128-CBC and AES-256-CBC with the correct key lengths.' in D:\wamp\www\***\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter.php:43
```

application key was set,my ajax request works well,but in sometimes for example after 5-7 consecutive request this error occurs

where is the problem?

Comment: Did you run `php artisan key:generate`?

Comment: yes,application key was set

Comment: It could be a configuration caching issue. Did you try to run `php artisan config:clear` and `php artisan config:cache`?

Comment: @piscator thank you so much,The problem was solved

Answer (score 1):

#### Application Key

The next thing you should do after installing Laravel is set your application key to a random string. If you installed Laravel via Composer or the Laravel installer, this key has already been set for you by the `php artisan key:generate` command.

[Official Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/installation#installing-laravel)

Comment: application key was set,my ajax request works well,but in sometimes for example after 5-7 consecutive request, this error occurs